# A different "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" issue

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5.3

OK... So... I've search SO and Google for this error, but all the answers I found where not relevant to my strange situation.

I just installed my first Laravel 5.3 app (worked with 5.2 earlier) to use for as local shopping list/price check app.

Trying to make a form:

ProductController:

```
$stores = Store::get();
return view('product.add', [
    'stores' => $stores,
]);
```

add.blade:

```
<select name="store_id" id="store_id">
@foreach ($stores as $store)
    <option value="{{ $store->id }}">{{ $store->name }} - {{ $store->address }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

This results in the following error:

```
ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 561:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: E:\wamp\www\shopping\resources\views\product\add.blade.php)
```

`$stores` is not empty, because `dd($stores)` produces a collection with all the stores in my database.

I compared this code and the `dd` results to other apps of mine that work as expected, all exactly the same. I even tried `@forelse`.

Is there anything changed in Laravel 5.3 that could influence this? Did I miss anything?

Comment: things getting weird, [FormBuilder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/4.2/src/Illuminate/Html) only found on laravel 4.. how did you upgrade your project? or rather, could you post your entire blade and a snippet of the offending code (FormBuilder line 560 - 565).

Comment: I'm using LaravelCollective for forms, which provides the Formbuilder.php mentioned.

Comment: Having said that, your comment pointed me in the right direction. Around line 560 this file handles the select input, which includes a `foreach` statement. Turns out I was looking at the wrong statement. I have another `select` input, which was done using the Form facade provided by LaravelCollective, with `null` as a option, which of course was producing this error. Thanks for pointing this out. Maybe as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: perhaps you can make your own answer as elaborate as possible, LaravelCollective is new for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem guys, thanks to a comment by @bagus-tesa.

The Formbuilder.php referred to in the error message was of [LaravelCollective Form & HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) ("We maintain Laravel components that have been removed from the core framework"), which made me go look at line 561 of that file. There was a `foreach` statement, which is used to build a select input. This made me realize that I had another select list in my form, so I looked at that.

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', null, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

The second argument should hold an array of options for the list, which is processed by Formbuilder with a `foreach` loop!

So... I just spent hours looking at the wrong `foreach` loop!

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. I think there is an empty array Array()

you must add if condition before loop  i.e

```
@if(!empty($stores))
@foreach ($stores as $store)
   <option value="{{ $store->id }}">{{ $store->name }} - {{ $store->address }}     </option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: The `dd` command already proved that the variable was not empty. I edited the post to say that I also tried `@forelse`.